# No ssh Connection to Google Cloud Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine, nmap

I cannot connect to my GCP VM through ssh. It is not working either through terminal (which gives a timeout error) or through the browser (eternally loading)

With nmap, I found out that there is no ssh service provided on the external IP address of the machine

```
Host is up (0.076s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp  closed http
443/tcp closed https
```

However, I do have the `default-allow-ssh`rule in my firewall.
My question is what I should do now to have this ssh access. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find in the official documentation :

[Troubleshooting
SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh)

> Test connectivity:
> Check your firewall rules,
> Test the network connection,
> Connect as a different user,
>
> Debug the issue in the serial console
>
> Inspect the VM instance without shutting it down
>
> Use a startup script
>
> Use your disk on a new instance